# How to pass row content as string argument using DataFrame.apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class A:
    def __int__(self):
        pass
    def to_lower(self,content_text):
        return content_text.lower()
```

I have a DataFrame with the following columns: `['From', 'To', 'Email Body']`.

Now, I want to pass `['Email Body']` to the above function as the parameter `content_text`.

Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
from somefile import A
processor = A()

messages_df_inbox.apply(processor.to_lower)
```

And it gives me this error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `messages_df_inbox['Email Body'].apply(processor.to_lower)`.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @AMC, I provided the class code and how I'm applying it and what the error I'm getting is. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: @dydx It shouldn't make a huge difference here, but it's the appropriate thing to do. Error tracebacks can reveal some issues which would have been very tough to find otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply by default apply your function .to_lower() to every column in messages_df_inbox. Since you want to apply to only email body, you can either

```
# Apply to Email body column only
messages_df_inbox['Email Body'].apply(processor.to_lower)
```

alternatively,

```
# Change your function to point to email body
class A:
    def __int__(self):
        pass
    def to_lower(self,content_text):
        return content_text['Email Body'].lower()

messages_df_inbox.apply(processor.to_lower, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply` goes row by row (or column by column if you pass `axis=1`) and calls the function you pass on each row (columns) of the dataframe. Since dataframe rows (column) are Series, you would expect the result you're getting.

If you want to apply an arbitrary function to a column, you want `df[col].map(func)`, but in your case if you want to lowercase the email column, just `df['Email Body'].str.lower()`. More info on string methods here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html